# Are there geometries in which points have finitely many parallel lines?

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

In Euclidian geometry the Parallel Postulate holds that given a parallel line as a reference there is one parallel line through any given point. In elliptic geometry there are no parallel lines. In hyperbolic geometry there are infinitely many parallel lines.

Are there geometries in which there is more than one, but finitely many, parallel lines through any given point?

Comment: if possible it will be pretty peculiar. In your three geometries, angles behave the same as far as betweenness. In particular, compass and straightedge are definable in all three settings, and an angle is constructible in one setting if and only if it is constructible in the others (major theorem, not mine). I don't see that you will have angles at all, so you are in a country next to the country of finite projective planes.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by geometry i.e. what specific axioms must hold. There are models for Hilbert's incidence axioms alone where your property holds, altough I'm not sure if they deserve the name geometry. However, adding betweenness axioms already makes it impossible.